# Deploy Django Application on Cloud, but even cannot get access to ip_address:8000

Tags: django, alibaba-cloud

I am a beginner on Django. And try to deploy a testproject on cloud server to check if it works or not.
Server: Ubuntu 16.04

And after I create virtualenv on the server with nginx installed.
I execute below:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And then I go to the browser to access my server's http://ip-address:8000.
But it failed to show anything of my application.

I already added the ip-address to ALLOWED_HOST. But still not working.

Are there any thoughts for this situation?

Comment: That's the development server. Read the Django docs on how to deploy. Then ask if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this method work for you because it worked for mine on the ec2 instance on Amazon web server.

step1: go to your dashboard find launch-wizard menu and open it.

step2: Now click on inbound after that click on edit. Here click on Add rule and select Custom TCP rule  & enter 8000 in port range. Now again click on Add rule and select HTTP and similarly do for HTTPS then click on save button.

step3: save and restart your AWS machine. Hopefully, your Django app runs on 8000 port.

Answer (score 0):

For a Linux instance in the security group, follow these steps to verify the security group rule:

1. Connect to a Linux instance by using a password.
2. Run the following command to check whether TCP 80 is being listened. `netstat -an | grep 80`

If the following result returns, web service for TCP port 80 is enabled.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

If not then there is a problem with your security group setup, please go through the official documentation and see how you can fix it:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25471.htm